A question about equidistributed sequence
The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$, meaning that for any interval $[a,b)⊂[0,1)$, let $S_n=\#\{1\le k\le n|a_k∈[a,b]\}$, the following limit exists:
$$\lim⁡_{n\to \infty} S_n=b−a$$
Obviously, in this definition, there is no requirement that this limit process is independent of the interval $[a,b)$.
That is, $\forall \varepsilon >0,∃N_{[a,b)}>0$, such that $ |S_n - (b - a)| < \varepsilon$
Now, if we require that this limit process is independent of $[a,b)$, that is, the choice of $N$ does not depend on $[a,b)$, is this strengthened definition equivalent to the original definition?
I think they are equivalent. My general idea is that $\displaystyle [0,1)=\bigcup_{i=0}^n[\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1}{n})$. For these small intervals, we can obtain a consistent $N$, and then use these small intervals to approximate $[a,b)$. Is this idea feasible?

Correction: you want to divide by $n$ in the definition of $S_n$, so  $S_n := (1/n)#{1\leq k \leq  n | a_k \in [a,b]}$.

It seems one can take $N$ to depend only on $\epsilon$ and the length of the subinterval (so that one has independence from the position of the subinterval); but the convergence rate will need to have a factor quantifying the size in any event.

That will work. First, choose a positive integer $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k}<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Then $[0,1)=\bigcup_{i=0}^{k-1}[\frac{i}{k},\frac{i+1}{k})$. Choose $n$ sufficiently large for each of these smaller intervals such that for $1\leq i\leq n$,$$|\frac{1}{n} #{ 1\leq j\leq n: a_j\in [\frac{i}{k},\frac{i+1}{k})} - \frac{1}{k}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2k}.$$Given an interval $[a,b)$, all of the smaller intervals will completely fit inside $[a,b)$ except a most 2 intervals, one that contains $a$ and one that contains $b$.  But, $k$ is large enough such that these two intervals are small. ...
